# How to skip iteration in foreach inside foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array of values, and i want to insert the values to another array but with an if condition, if the "if" is true I want to skip the iteration.

Code:

```
$array=array(array(1=>11,2=>22,3=>23,4=>44,5=>55));
$insert=array();
foreach($array as $k1=>$v1)
{
foreach($v1 as $k2=>$v2)
{
    if($v2==23)
    {
        break; 
    }
}
    $insert[]=$v1;
}
```

final result should look like that

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [1] => 11
        [2] => 22
        [3] => 44
        [4] => 55
    )
)
```

I tried using: break,return,continue...

Thanks

Comment: `continue` should work

Comment: You don't do anything in your inner loop, so breaking out of it will not change anything either. From what it looks like, you don't need the inner loop at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. You can loop over the outer array and use [array_filter](http://www.php.net/array_filter) on the inner array to remove where the value is `23` like this (IMO preferred; this also uses an array of `$dontWant` numbers so it is easier to add or change numbers later):

```
<?php
$array = array(array(1=>11,2=>22,3=>23,4=>44,5=>55));
$insert = array();

//array of numbers you don't want
$dontWant = array(23);

//loop over outer array    
foreach($array as $subArray){
    //add to $insert a filtered array
    //subArray is filtered to remove where value is in $dontWant
    $insert[] = array_filter($subArray, function($val) uses ($dontWant) {
        //returns true if the value is not in the array of numbers we dont want
        return !in_array($val, $dontWant);
    });
}
//display final array    
echo '<pre>'.print_r($insert,1).'</pre>';
```

Or you can reference the first key to add to a sub array in `$insert` like (which is a little more like what your code is trying to do and show that you are not too far off):

```
<?php
$array = array(array(1=>11,2=>22,3=>23,4=>44,5=>55));
$insert = array();
//loop over outer array    
foreach($array as $k1=>$v1){
    //add an empty array to $insert
    $insert[$k1] = array();

    //loop over inner array
    foreach($v1 as $k2=>$v2){
        //if the inner array value is not 23
        if($v2 != 23){
            //add to inner array in insert
            $insert[$k1][] = $v2;
        }
    }
}
//display the result    
echo '<pre>'.print_r($insert,1).'</pre>';
```

Both of these methods would produce the same result. IMO using array_filter is the preferred method, but the second method might be a little easier to understand for someone new to programming.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just try it like this?

```
foreach($v1 as $k2=>$v2)
{
    if($v2!=23)
    {
      $insert[]=$v2;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Explanation: You check with the if($v2!=23) if the value of the variable `$v2` is not equal to (that is the `!=` sign) any given number that stands after the inequality operator, and if so, it will insert that value to the array `$insert`.

I hope it is clear now.

Sorry, I've written $v1 instead of $v2, the code should work now.

Comment: And what does "like this" entail? Explanations make answers better

Comment: I've edited my answer with a short explanation, sorry if you did not understand it right away.

Comment: `$v1` is an array set from the outer loop. Your code will add that array to `$insert` once for each key inside of itself where the value is `!= 23`. You are just adding duplicate values to the `$insert` array, not removing where value is 23 from the inner array.

Comment: it's closer, but still not 100% there. `$insert` is a 2d array.

Answer (score 1):

To add variants :)

```
$array=array(array(1=>11,2=>22,3=>23,4=>44,5=>55));
$insert=array();

foreach($array as $a)
{
    while (($i = array_search(23, $a)) !== false) 
        { unset($a[$i]); sort($a); }
    $insert[] = $a;
}   
print_r($a);
```

result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 22 [2] => 44 [3] => 55 ) )
```